# How to determine what the actual error is in an Oracle stored procedure, when "execution completed with warning"?

Tags: oracle11g

I am using the following code

```
create or replace procedure phys_last_year_sales_sp (amdm_phys_id number(6))

is  
begin 

dbms_output.put_line('amdm_phys_id= '||amdm_phys_id);

end;
```

to create stored procedure but every time I execute above query it shows the following error

> java.sql.SQLWarning: Warning: execution completed with warning

How do I find out what the actual error is?

Comment: What front-end are you using to create your procedure?  You're getting a JDBC error which seems odd-- you wouldn't normally be writing Java code in order to create a stored procedure.

Comment: i am using sql explorer

Comment: Life is probably going to be easier if you use Oracle's free GUI (SQL Developer).  You could query `user_errors` every time you're trying to develop code but that will get pretty old pretty quickly.